# Compute P(X=Y) when X and Y are i.i.d. geometrically distributed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables each having the same geometric distribution. We need to find $P(X=Y)$.

I tried as follows :

Let us say $X$~$Geo(p)$ and $Y$~$Geo(\theta)$.

$P(X=Y) = \sum_{y} P(X=Y|Y=y)P(Y=y) =>\sum_{y} P(X=y)P(Y=y)$.

=> $\sum_{y} p(1-p)^{y-1} \theta(1- \theta)^{y-1}$ => $\sum_{y} (p \theta)[(1-p)(1- \theta)]^{y-1} $  => $ \dfrac{p \theta}{1-(1-p)(1- \theta)}$

Is this correct ? (The independence condition is never used ).

Comment: Well, you use independence when you write that the probability that both equal $y$ is the product of the two probabilities.  Absent independence...well, if $X=Y$ the answer is $1$, for example.

Comment: Specifically, you use independence when you write $P(X=y\,|\,Y=y)=P(X=y)$.  Also worth pointing out...in this set up, we have $p=\theta$, no?

Comment: That statement is quite ambiguous don't you think ? If $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution with same parameter then the solution to the question $P(X=Y) is simply 1. @lulu

Comment: Please read the description of the tag (distribution-theory) before (mis)using it.

Comment: No it isn't.  I can flip one coin, while you flip another. The probability that we get our first  $H$ on the same trial is not $1$.

Comment: I am sorry. I'll take care of it next time. @Did

Comment: I even tried working with $MGF$'s taking $X-Y = Z$ and using its distribution but it didn't help( P(Z=0) ). @lulu

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the approach you took!  You correctly invoked independence even if you didn't mean to and you solved a more general problem (in which the two processes were independent and geometric, but had possibly different parameters).

Comment: Where is the problem at this point? Your derivation looks to be correct (at worst there is a fencepost error that I don't want to check for) and it uses the independence hypothesis.

Comment: I just got confused I guess , $X$ and $Y$ having the same distributions. I've got it now. Thanks. @Ian

Comment: Understood. Thank you. @lulu

Answer (score 3):

First, there are two styles of geometric random variable. Yours
counts the *trials* until the first Success, the other counts
*Failures* until the first Success.

Second, 'iid' means independent and *identically distributed*, so
that you need to have $p = \theta.$ In case $p = \theta = 1/3,$
your answer computes to $1/(9-4) = 1/5 = 0.200.$

Finally, from the discussion in the Comments, I am not entirely
certain you believe you are on the right track. So I will show you
results of a simulation in R statistical software with a million
realizations of $X$ and $Y$ with $p = 1/3.$

```
m = 10^6     # iterations
x = rgeom(m, 1/3)+1;  y = rgeom(m, 1/3)+1  # independent counts of 'trials'
mean(x == y)
## 0.200079  # Consistent with P(X = Y) = 1/5
```

Notes: (1) Because R uses the 'other'
version of the geometric random variable, I add $1$ to each
realization in order to match the model you are using.
(2) The comparison vector `x == y` has a million entries, each
of then either `TRUE` (for equality) or `FALSE`. The `mean` of
this vector is its proportion of `TRUE`s. (3) With a million
iterations, the answer should be correct to three decimal places.
*So the answer is consistent with your derivation.*

Comment: +1 I have been meaning to ask you, is there a resource you recommend for learning R?

Comment: Grolemund G, Wickham H (2014) Hands-on programming with R, O’Reilly. For statistical analysis with R: Dalgaard, Peter (2008) Intro Statistics with R, Springer. Maybe to start immediately, google 'getting started with R` and take your choice of intro tutorials. Install R from `www.r-project.org` free for Windows, Mac, UNIX machines. This is a huge, comprehensive package; start by focusing on just the parts that are of immediate interest or use to you. (Probably nobody knows everything about R.)

Comment: Excellent response. Thanks @BruceET!